# Basic electrical circuit problem

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current

I came across a very basic problem in electrical circuits (self studying)

Find v,i  and the power of the voltage source in the following electrical circuit.

[image]

I am thinking to minimize the circuit after finding all the resistors that are in series and parallel (from right to left) and then apply Ohm's Law $$I =v /R$$.For example 8 and 4 resistors are in series so they make a resistor of 12 ohms.Then this resulted resistor is in parallel with the 6 ohm resistor and so on.Am I correct ?

Procceding in the calculations I end up with a single resistor of 10 ohms because :R1: 2 ohm is in parallel with R2:16 ohm ,in series with R3:12 ohm.R3 is connected in parallel with  R4: 6 ohm and in series with R5:4 ohm.

Applying Ohm's Law $$I=\frac{V}{R}=\frac{30V}{10\Omega}=3A$$

To find the voltage across R6, we can use Ohm's law again. Since R6 is in series with R5, we can first calculate the voltage drop across R5:

$$V_{R5} = I * R_5$$
$$V_{R5} = 3 * 4$$
$$V_{R5} = 12 V$$

Next, i calculated the voltage drop across R6 by subtracting the voltage drop across R5 from the total voltage of the circuit:

$$V_{R6} = V_total - V_R5$$
$$V_{R6} = 30 - 12$$
$$V_{R6} = 18 V$$

Therefore, the voltage across R_6 is 18 V.
The power is $$p=vi=30*3=90 W$$

Comment: yes, that is the way to proceed. Successive replacement by equivalents for series and parallel components works for many circuits, including this one. However, it won't work for all circuits. At some point, however, you will need to learn the delta-wye transformation.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Thank you for the confirmation.I have added some calculations.Can you check these as well?I will appreciate it.

Comment: No, your calculation is wrong. Notice that the voltage across the 16Ω resistor is  30V - 3A*2Ω = 24V. Also, notice that 3A is only flowing through a 2-ohms resistor.  Do you see it?

Comment: @G36 so what are the correct calculations go this circuit ? (Assuming R6 is the 8 ohm resistor in the right.)

Comment: Don't you want to try to calculate it yourself?

Comment: @G36 I am confused now from your comment.It asks for the voltage across 8 ohm resistor not the 16 ohm.What I am missing here ? Why the current flows only on the  2 ohm resistor ? Not in the other circuit ?

Comment: You started off correctly seeing the 8 ohm and 4 ohm in series make 12. Then 12 in parallel with 6 makes 4. Your calculation of 10 total is correct, but your wording of "2 ohms is in parallel with 16 etc" shows confusion. The 2 ohms is in _series_ with the rest of the circuit. Back up, explain it again, but be careful about what is parallel with what and what is in series with what.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I apologize.Yes they are in series 2 ohm with the rest resistors , who break down to a single resistor of 8 ohms.So the simplified circuit has a single resistor of 2+8 =10 ohm.That's why I did 30/10=3A.

Comment: Ok. Fix that. Then knowing the current through R1, find the voltage drop across R1. Then you can find the voltage across R2. Then the current through R2. Then the current through R3, the voltage across R3, the voltage across R4, the current through R4, etc.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy now I got it.Thank you.